# bash_history does not work outside session El-Capitan after installing ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, osx-elcapitan

in mac osx el-capitan .bash_history has stopped working when i close the window or session after i installed ruby (using either rvm or rbebnv) the last lines recorded by bash_history are;

> rvm get stable --autolibs=enable

OR

> rbenv install 2.3.0

If i comment out below lines in .bash_profile and .profile, .bash_history resumes...

> [[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile
>
> [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *$

OR

> if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

I want to work on rails with a bash history.

Please let me know if i can get bash history working

Comment: Try `set -o history`.  I can't explain why it would be switched off though.

Comment: Please let me know where should add this line in bash_profile or profile

Comment: Does the `set -o history` work?  Without seeing more of your start-up files I can't be sure.   Why do you have both?  Usually only .bash_profile is necessary, I would put the `set -o history` at the end of the .bash_profile.  This assumes there are no `exec` commands anywhere.

Comment: Sadly [link]set -o history does not seem to work.

Comment: OK, does `set` report `history` on or off?  Second, is there a `.sh_history` in your home directory, and what is the time last written (relative to the time you are looking at it)?

Comment: i managed to get the bash_history working after i did this: I clicked on preferences > shell > selected the option **when shell exists** dont close the window

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem, it was [resolved here](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3540).
Simply update your RVM using `rvm get head`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a `.bash_logout` file with the following:

```
shell_session_update
```

[Sourced from GitHub comment](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3540#issuecomment-152824133)